# How to modify drop event in QListView

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qlistview

I have a `QListView` where items can be reordered with drag-and-drop by setting dragDropMode to DragDrop and defaultDropAction to MoveAction. How can I intercept the drop event, to find out what is trying to be moved where in relation to the rest of the list, so that I can cancel this action under certain conditions? E.g. I want to forbid moving some items behind other.

Comment: Subclass and implement the [`dropEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#dropEvent) or use an event filter if the operation is not too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the indexes and items involved in the `dropEvent` and setDropAction to `Qt.IgnoreAction` to cancel the drop depending on your criteria. Since you weren't specific, for this demonstration I just created one item that stays at the bottom.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class List(QListView):

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        i = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
        j = self.indexAt(event.pos())

        # To access the items involved
        source = self.model().itemFromIndex(i)
        target = self.model().itemFromIndex(j)

        bottom = (self.model().rowCount() - 1, -1)
        if i.row() in bottom or j.row() in bottom:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)
        else:
            super().dropEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    lv = List()
    lv.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
    lv.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
    
    model = QStandardItemModel(5, 1)
    for i in range(4):
        item = QStandardItem(f'Item {i + 1}')
        item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)
        model.setItem(i, 0, item)    
    item = QStandardItem('I stay at the bottom ._.')
    model.setItem(4, 0, item)
    lv.setModel(model)
    
    vbox = QVBoxLayout(window)
    vbox.addWidget(lv)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Could you elaborate on the use of `~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled`? I don't understand why this is inverted? When I remove the tilda items1-4 become inactive (grey and can't be selected).

Comment: @MJB The ItemIsDropEnabled flag is enabled by default, and when that's the case you can drop one item into another item, resulting in the latter being removed/replaced. So `& ~ItemIsDropEnabled` removes that flag and that behavior. If you do want that feature then delete the whole line, removing just the `~` would result in an invalid bitwise OR of the flags.